# Syntax for C# Array[] in C++/CLI

Tags: c#, syntax, c++-cli

I have an interface defined in C# which has a method

```
Array[] Foo();
```

I need to implement this interface in a class written in C++/CLI.
i tried the following syntax

```
array<array<Object^>^>^ Foo();
```

But i get an error stating my return type does not match the one in the interface.
Does anyone know how to translate a C# `Array[]` to C++/CLI?

Answer (score 7):

I'd say the syntax is:

```
cli::array<Array^>^ Foo();
```

Comment: array<Array^ >^ Foo() turned out right. Thank you. I wish i knew why, but it works.

Comment: @eithan: please close your question by marking this correct answer.  Click the big check mark next to this post.

Comment: @eithan: as for the why: The ^'s are there to signify that the object is passed by reference(managed pointer). This is redundant, but it is in the spirit of the C++ syntax. Without it, a C++ mind may misread the above declaration. The redundancy ensures everybody reads it the same. (P.S. my fingers hurt after a day C++/CLI).